# Manually remove last legacy exchange server from the domain after the exchange server has failed

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2003, exchange-2010, windows-sbs-2011, windows-sbs-2003

Before we completed the migration from sbs 2003 to sbs 2011 the server running sbs 2003 failed so we were unable to carry out the steps required to remove the last legacy exchange server i.e we can not access the Exchange 2003 System Manager .

When we run the Microsoft Exchange Best Practices Analyser on the 2011 server we receive the following warnings:

1. Cannot not connect to port 25 of the routing group master
2. Cannot not connect to port 691 of the routing group master
3. Exchange Server *machine name* could not be contacted

   - How can we manually update active directory so that the failed machine is no longer listed as an exchange server? (the machine account no longer exists)
   - How can we designate the 2011 server as the routing group master?